# I didn't understand the create element function in javascript

Tags: javascript

Suppose I write following JavaScript code:-

```
//Line1

document.createElement("button");

//Line2
document.createElement("button").onclick="func();
```

Now question is what will happen next
Scenario 1 :- JavaScript will create two buttons.
Scenario 2:- JavaScript will create 1 button with onclick attribute.
If scenario 2 is true how JavaScript created attribute in 2nd line without calling getelement function.means how JavaScript was knowing that I am still working on previous button and not asking to create a new button.

I am a beginner and this is my first time posting question so forgive for mistakes.

Comment: Your frst step should *always* be to *test* your code.  (After correcting your syntax error, of course.)  When you execute your code and observe its results, what happens?  How does it differ from what you expected to happen?  What did you expect to happen?  Why?

Answer (score 0):

The createElement function creates a new element and returns it.

So here you will create 2 different buttons (one for each time you called the function).

You can see that the second time you are calling createElement, it is not the same as the first one. You can test that like this to make sure:

```
a = document.createElement("button")
b = document.createElement("button")
a == b // false
```

This will return false because they are different.

So as a and b are both elements created, you can call

```
a.onclick = function() {}
// or
b.onclick = function() {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Both the lines when executed, creates two different elements and returns them. Note that they are not yet added to the DOM and since the returned elements are not captured in any variable, they can't be added to DOM later.

Here's the correct way of creating and adding a button in the DOM:

```js
var button = document.createElement('button');
button.innerText = "Button1";
button.onclick = handler;

document.getElementById('parent').appendChild(button);
```

Comment: If both returns 2 different elements than consider this example.      
Suppose
//Line1

var a=document.createElement("button");

//Line2
a.onclick="func()"

This time it returns only one element although it is the same code as var a is just pointer to the 1st line.

So 

document.createElement("button").onclick="func()
 
and
a.onclick="func()";

are same thing but they show different results as 1st code shows 2 buttons and 2nd code shows 1 button.